# Is it possible to add the entire eclipse Plugin Project to a Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have developed an eclipse Plugin Project with SampleFormPage with multiple forms with using formtoolkit and formPage.
Now I want to change the scenario of the project and want to change the eclipse Plugin project to Eclipse RCP standalone application.

Is it possible to do?
If yes, what all the measures I should keep in mind while developing.

Example Of the scenario is like-
*Consider the file plugin.xml editor in eclipse. Now the same entire application I want to put in RCP application.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create an RCP application based on a plugin. After all, writing an RCP app basically amounts to writing a set of plugins for the platform. Take a look at [this](http://cyberpen.wordpress.com/2008/06/16/convertion-of-a-plugin-to-a-standalone-rcp-application/) tutorial.

Comment: Broken link - no content.